# Unable to set cookie with Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm new to Node js; I'm tring to understand how to get and set cookie with Node. 
I'm using Visual Studio, and I'm using the embedded IIS Express that is create automatically. 
There is the server code on my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:61342');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.get('/setCookie/:param', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('testCookie', req.params.param);
    console.log('cookie created!');
    res.send();
});

var server = app.listen(8001, 'localhost', function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

And this is the client code:

```
function server() { 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8001/setCookie/cookie1", true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert("ok");
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

I call this funcion when I click on a button (just for testing).
I notice that if I type localhost:8001/getCookie/cookie1
it set correctly the cookie (I can see it on the browser console, typing document.cookie),
but if I run my project on localhost:61342/ and I click the button that call the function server(), I get this response :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8001/setCookie/cookie1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8001

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:61342
Connection:keep-alive
Set-Cookie:testCookie=cookie1; Path=/
```

but when I type on browser console document.cookie I don't see anything.
Any idea on how can I solve this?
Thank you for the patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.

First:

`document.cookie` will show the cookies belonging to the origin of the *document*. Cross-origin Ajax requests will send and store cookies for the origin they are making the request to. Since that is a different origin, they won't show up in `document.cookie`. To inspect them you would need to make a request to the origin to which they belong and inspect it in the Network tab.

Second:

Cross-origin requests don't support cookies by default. You have to [set `withCredentials`](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute) to `true` first.